# Detect background vim after :sh

Tags: vim

I often use the **:sh** command while using vim (to do a grep for example).

But sometimes I forgot I had a vim running behind my shell.

Is there a command to detect that I have a vim running behind my shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see if Vim-specific shell variables are set:

```
$ echo $VIM
$ echo $VIMRUNTIME
$ echo $MYVIMRC
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have an environment variable set called `VIM`, you can see if this is then set

```
 $ echo $VIM
```

Note, it's also possible (unlikely) that $VIM is set when you're just in your shell normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the parent process:

```
$ ps -p $PPID -o cmd=
vi file
```

Or to be independent of environment variables:

```
$ ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o cmd=
vi file
```